# Separate auth for customers and staff portal in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've been searching for information about this, but what I find is only multi authorization for roles etc.

On my website I will have main website available for regular users(customers) who will be stores in separate table. Staff section will have different users/user groups as this will be food ordering website.

How should I deal with this? The login forms and information needed for customers and staff portal will be different. Basically - 2 different apps connected together in one place.

Comment: Use multiple guards. https://mattstauffer.com/blog/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-5-2/